# laravel-ffmpeg - fopen(/tmp/laravel-ffmpegi340VY.mkv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

Using the [laravel-ffmpeg](https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg) librabry to convert video file from .webm to mp4 aws s3 bucket url and using following code.

```
$videoFile = '/courses/images/1579626678msr-2020-01-21T17-11-18-771Z.webm';  //= upload/video1.mp4
   FFMpeg::fromDisk('s3')
    ->open($videoFile)
    ->getFrameFromSeconds(10)
    ->export()
    ->toDisk('s3')
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264)
    ->save('small_steve.mp4');
```

How can access file from s3 bucket and convert?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code and using fromDesk('public') add public before the file path.

```
FFMpeg::fromDisK('s3')->open('/courses/images/1579626678msr-2020-01-21T17-11-18-771Z.webm')
      ->export()
      ->toDisk('s3')
      ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libfdk_aac'))
      ->save('output2.mp4');
```